# Nginx showing blank page on my website after upgrading

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-14.04

I upgraded my nginx package via apt-upgrade (running ubuntu 14.04) and now, when I've tried to connect to my website, it only shows a blank page (no error message).

This is what my nginx configuration file looks like:

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.example.com;
        root /home/forge/example.com/public;

        # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
        # ssl on;
        # ssl_certificate;
        # ssl_certificate_key;

        index index.html index.htm index.php;

        charset utf-8;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

        access_log off;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/example.com-error.log error;

        error_page 404 /index.php;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
        }

    }

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;
    return       301 http://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Also, the  error.log shows this message:  `conflicting server name "www.example.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored`

Answer (score 0):

Second time today I'm seeing the use of fastcgi_split_pathinfo without setting a document root and path info setting. Where does that come from? In addition the match is on `\.php$`, so it won't ever match on path info requests.

I'm guessing there lies the root of your problem as fastcgi_params has been upgraded.